# show a div depending on the selection

Tags: jquery, css, list, menu

I have the following http://jsbin.com/useqa4/10

My question is this: In the submenu I hover some li elements using the following

```
$(".submenuList li").hover(function () {
  $(".submenuCurrent").removeClass("submenuCurrent");
  $(this).addClass("submenuCurrent");
  });
```

When I rollover on any of these the right section I want to change and show a specific div.

For example:

- for the first li the div
  `#prasentRight`
- for the second li the div `#elitRight`
- for the third li the div
  `#suspendisseRight`
- for the forth li the div
  `#laoreetRight`

My difficult is that I don't know how to get the current index of `.submenuList li`

Any help?

Comment: It'd be better to use an attribute of some sort, say `data-id` or `data-div`, but to get the index it's just `var i = $(this).index();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this should work:

```
$('submenuList li').hover(
  function(){
    var thisIndex = $(this).index();
    $(this).attr('title',thisIndex);
  });
```

Shows the current index of the hovered-over list items in the `title` attribute of the element, [demo at JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/useqa4/11/edit).

Comment: Thanks you David! I am at this step now http://jsbin.com/useqa4/16 How can I prevent the divs from this behavior they have when they change? if I use show() alone there isn't problem, but I need to slide then and it has wrong behavior when I move fast my cursor. What can I do for this? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Sotiris, honestly? I'd ask another question and hope that @Nick Craver or @Patrick dw answers it... Sorry =/